# Aligning div to another Div

Tags: html, css

I want to align my two divs. When I change screen resolution divs look weird. Here is picture of 1440 x 900 resoluton:

[1440x900](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBKdw.png)

And here is 1920 x 1080 screen:

[1920x1080](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNXiF.png)

I want to align 2nd div to first in order for screen to look like in the second picture, no matter the resolution.

Here is my Code :

```css
.totalPriceDiv {
  float: right;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-right: 22%;
}

.totalPrice {
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  color: black;
  border: none;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 0.115rem;
}

.totalPriceItem {
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  color: black;
  border: none;
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 0.115rem;
}
```

```html
<h1>My project</h1>
<div class="input_div">
  <input class="inputMovieName" type="text" placeholder="Input 1">
  <input class="inputMoviePrice" type="text" placeholder="Input 2">
  <button class="addButton">Button</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="itemFirstRow">
    <input type="text" class="item_input" disabled value="#">
    <input type="text" class="item_input" disabled value="Input 1">
    <input type="text" class="item_input" disabled value="Input 2">
  </div>

  <ul id="the-ul">

  </ul>

</div>

<div class="totalPriceDiv">
  <div>
    <input type="text" class="totalPrice" disabled value="First: ">
    <input id="totalAmount" type="text" class="totalPriceItem" value="0" disabled>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" class="totalPrice" disabled value="Second: ">
    <input id="discount" type="text" class="totalPriceItem" value="0" disabled>
  </div>
  <div id="border">
    <input type="text" class="totalPrice" disabled value="Third: ">
    <input id="afterDiscount" type="text" class="totalPriceItem" value="0" disabled>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

Comment: You can't combine `float` and CSS flexbox at the same time (not for now). What you can do is to use `align-items: flex-end` and perhaps reduce the width of `.totalPriceItem` (it is currently 200px and probably a bit too much).

Answer (score 0):

wrap your both div with a "div container" which will a css like this :

```css
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

And for your last div (i think is "totalPriceDiv") set your css with :

```css
align-self: flex-end
```

and replace your margin and padding values ('rem', '%') by a fixed value ("px") or set this margin to the div container.

practice with this tool : [flexy-boxes](https://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/?fixed-height=on&display=flex&flex-direction=column&flex-wrap=nowrap&justify-content=flex-start&align-items=flex-start&align-content=stretch&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=0&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=stretch&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=0&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=flex-end&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=0&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto)

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution. You just follow basic bootstrap framework structure.

`

```
 <div class="container">
    <h1>xxxx</h1>
    <div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-offset-3 col-6">
          Bootstrap form-group code comes here 
    </div>
    </div> <div class="row"> block1</div>


    </div>
```

`

Then it automatically behaves in responsive way.

Answer (score 0):

Also, arrange using `grid columns`. like `display: grid;` and `grid-gap: 10px;`,

```css
.input_div {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
}

.itemFirstRow {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
}

.totalPriceDiv {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 1rem;
}

.totalPriceDiv > div {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.totalPrice {
    background: none;
    outline: none;
    color: black;
    border: none;
    width: 100px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    padding: 0.115rem;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

.totalPriceItem {
    background: none;
    outline: none;
    color: black;
    border: none;
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    padding: 0.115rem;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>

  <body>
      <h1>My project</h1>
      <div class="input_div">
        <input class="inputMovieName" type="text" placeholder="Input 1">
        <input class="inputMoviePrice" type="text" placeholder="Input 2">
        <button class="addButton">Button</button>
      </div>
      <br/>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="itemFirstRow">
          <input type="text" class="item_input" disabled value="#">
          <input type="text" class="item_input" disabled value="Input 1">
          <input type="text" class="item_input" disabled value="Input 2">
        </div>

        <ul id="the-ul">

        </ul>

      </div>

      <div class="totalPriceDiv">
        <div>
          <input type="text" class="totalPrice" disabled value="First: ">
          <input id="totalAmount" type="text" class="totalPriceItem" value="0" disabled>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" class="totalPrice" disabled value="Second: ">
          <input id="discount" type="text" class="totalPriceItem" value="0" disabled>
        </div>
        <div id="border">
          <input type="text" class="totalPrice" disabled value="Third: ">
          <input id="afterDiscount" type="text" class="totalPriceItem" value="0" disabled>
        </div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

`grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));`.

I think it will work.

check below the given example.